# How to disable Heads Up notifications in Android Lollipop? (notification popup at top of the screen)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications

How can I disable the heads up for Android Lollipop, just like it was in KitKat and below?

If it is possible to disable heads up, is it also possible to enable it for certain apps only , like when I receive a call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A non root option is now available. The [HeadsOff](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jamworks.noheadsup) app can disable all Lollipop Heads-up notifications on your phone. It can also disable Heads-up notifications only for selected apps. If you purchase the [Pro key](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jamworks.noheadsup.pro) you can restore the ticker text in the status-bar to see a little notification preview.

Answer (score 5):

On Cyanogenmod 12.1+ (including CM13) there is by default an option to enable or disable heads up notifications. Just go to `Settings -> Notifications -> Heads up` There you can enable or disable the heads up notifications.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is using adb:

`adb shell settings put global heads_up_notifications_enabled 0`

([Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/howto-4-to-disable-heads-notifications-t3197660))

Comment: im going to try this... last time I modified directly the db... this seem easier

Answer (score 2):

I presume your device is Rooted.
You will need Xposed for Lollipop. Get from [here (Official Xposed Lollipop thread)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811)

1. Download, install it and reboot.
2. Open Xposed app and install module named "Restore Notification Ticker on Lollipop". OR manually download from [Xposed module repository here](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.mohammadag.enablenotificationtickeronlollipop) and install it.
3. Update and Reboot.
4. Done. Now that head up will no longer bother you. Cheers

Source: [Swap Heads Up Notifications for the Old-Style Ticker in Android Lollipop](http://nexus5.wonderhowto.com/how-to/swap-heads-up-notifications-for-old-style-ticker-android-lollipop-0160381/)