# I'm going crazy trying to sort WhatsApp notifications on Lollipop - help, please?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications, whatsapp-messenger, sony-xperia

I've got a Sony Xperia Z3 Compact, and it's on Lollipop 5.0.2. What I want to do is this:

- Vibrate when I get a WhatsApp message, when it's set to vibrate.
- The pop-up bar that comes up at the top when I'm on the phone when I receive a message NOT to appear.
- When the screen is turned off, for the notification NOT to appear and turn the screen on.

I can't seem to get a combination of the 3. I managed to stop the pop-up bar and stop the screen turned off notifications, but it wouldn't vibrate. Now I've managed to get it to vibrate and the screen turned off notifications don't come up, but the pop-up bar at the top appears when I'm using the phone and receive a message.

I've attempted all the usual ways and can't seem to get it how I want it, so I'm hoping that someone else has stumbled upon a solution for a similar problem, as the settings you'd expect to change to make it work, don't seem to work. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Solution is a custom lollipop rom. I use AICP and it lets me disable heads up notifications

Comment: @joaquin there are also non root ways to disable the Heads Up notifications on lollipop.

Answer (score 1):

The popup bar at the top is called **Heads up notification**.

There are multiple ways you can disable them. For example there are ways to do it **with root** and **without root**. For more information how to disable them, look at this question: [**Android 5.x Disable Heads Up**](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/112461).
In the accepted answer of that question there is a link to an app that can disable them for you without root. If you purchase the pro version for that app you can also restore the **notification ticker** like in **Android Kitkat** and below and even select to only disable heads up for certain apps like **Whatsapp**. For more information about the pro version look in the **apps description**.

Hope my answer helps!