# How to disable whatsapp pop notification?

Tags: stock-android

-I just want to disable the annoying           whtsapp headsup notification on lollipop. 
-I dont want to Completely stop the notification by unchecking the "show notification" option in the application manager.

Comment: You want to disable not completely stop?  Both are contradictory.Please edit and state your intention

Comment: @beeshyams I want notification only to appear in notification panel not as a popup. I tried to disable it through the app but still it appears as popup.I think this is a lollipop feature.

Comment: Which Android version? In Android 5.1, you can manage the heads-up notification on per app basis or perhaps it is a custom ROM feature, I can't tell for sure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A non root option is now available. The HeadsOff app can disable all Lollipop Heads-up notifications on your phone. It can also disable Heads-up notifications only for selected apps. If you purchase the Pro key you can restore the ticker text in the status-bar to see a little notification preview.

Original post : [How to disable Heads Up notifications in Android Lollipop? (notification popup at top of the screen)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105902/how-to-disable-heads-up-notifications-in-android-lollipop-notification-popup-a)

Comment: Please see [Is it okay to copy-paste answers from other questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78658)  and [Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160078) The acceptable way is to either flag the question if it is a duplicate of the original, or link the answer in the comments, or, quote the relevant part from the original answer in your answer followed by proper attribution to the author and making the post a community wiki. This solves the issue of amassing reputation from somebody's work..

Comment: @Firelord I think if user has mentioned the original post (which in the case it is), there's no problem.

Comment: @SantoshKumar, no,  there is a problem: the first step of proper attribution requires  mentioning both the link as well as the author's name. It hasn't been done here. Second, if you're mentioning something word by word from somewhere, then differentiate it from the rest of the content by using quotes. Third, it would constitute as good etiquette for making the post a community one if you have nothing further to add. // Your reasoning can be considered applicable for those cases where the link is additional or supplementary but not important to understand the origin of current answer.

Comment: Anyhow, it's not that I want to argue here. I voted the answer and simply explained why I did so. It is up to the poster from now on, whether to become better or maintain status quo.