# How to disable popup/heads up notifications globally in Android 9 Pie?

Tags: notifications, 9.0-pie, popup

I recently upgraded to a Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 9 Pie installed. It has an annoying feature, each time I e.g. get a message via Telegram, a pop-up window appears over any other application I am currently using on top of the screen:

[image: screenshot of an annoying telegram popup notification on the BBC news app]

I want to disable that for *all* apps. I found [this reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/99ytjf/android_pie_how_do_i_disable_heads_uppeekpop/):

> When you're in notification settings for an app, there's the label for
>   the notification channel and the checkbox next to it. Checking the
>   checkbox enables/disables notifications entirely. Tapping the label,
>   as unintuitive as it is, brings you to the advanced settings where you
>   can disable pop up/sound/vibrations.

If I go to e.g. Settings>Notifications>Telegram, I can tap each single chat and disable pop-ups. This is tedious, surely there is a global option to turn this invasive feature off?

Comment: On a regular Android device you can configure notification in Settings -> Apps and Notifications -> scoll down and disable notifications every listed app. But as you are on a Samsung device this may be a bit different as Samsung does not want it make it users that easy...

Comment: Related topic: [How to disable Heads Up notifications in Android Lollipop?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105902/how-to-disable-heads-up-notifications-in-android-lollipop-notification-popup-a?rq=1), [How to disable Peek / Heads Up notifications globally in Android Oreo?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/194058/how-to-disable-peek-heads-up-notifications-globally-in-android-oreo?rq=1)

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks. So it seems in 5.0 you need an app do disable these notifications, and in 8.0 you need a command line tool but then the setting is gone once you restart the phone. In the words of AVGN, _what were they thinking?_

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is!

1. Set-up adb. Use [THIS](https://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/) for reference
2. Enter `adb devices` and make sure your device is there
3. Enter `adb shell settings put global heads_up_notifications_enabled 0`
   And you're done!

If you want to enable it again then just replace the command in step 3 with `adb shell settings put global heads_up_notifications_enabled 1`

Simple as that!

Comment: This is the best answer for disabling it for all apps. I don't want to go through the settings for all apps... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My S9+ is running Androud 10 UI2 and Telegram 6.0.1
I had the same issue which I finally solved. I went all through the app settings, then i tried android-apps-telegram settings with no luck.
I finally looked in android-settings-notifications and down at the bottom it says "looking for something else?" Click on the Smart pop-up view option and shut telegram off.

Comment: Awesome, they actually listened to the users apparently! For Android 9 I ended up solving it with the Android Debug Bridge as linked to in the comment by @Andrew T.

Comment: My S9 is running Android 10 by now and this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The in-app solution for Telegram 7.1.3 on Android 10:

`Menu` -> `Settings` -> `Notifications and Sounds` -> `Private chats` (or `Groups` or `Channels`) -> set `Importance` from `Urgent` to `High`